# Split pandas column with list of item and values, into separate columns with item as column header

Tags: python, pandas, split

I have a column in a pandas DataFrame that looks like the below:

```
[Apple X 1, Orange X 2, Watermelon X 1, Pineapple X 3]
```

There are 100k+ rows, and it represents things our customers have ordered.

I'd like to go through this column and split these into separate columns so that the items become column names and the number becomes the value, for that particular row.

E.g

```
Apple   Orange   Watermelon   Pineapple
    1       2        1            3
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you can we can use `split` and `set_index`, then `T`, for transpose:

```
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series(['Apple X 1', 'Orange X 2', 'Watermelon X 1', 'Pineapple X 3'])
s.str.split(' ', expand=True).set_index(0).T.drop(1)
```

Output:

```
0 Apple Orange Watermelon Pineapple
2     1      2          1         3
```